# dynamically populating drop down box not working with 'spaces'

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamic drop down box which one the first selection, populates the second drop down from the database.

```
include("connect.php");
$choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE county_name='$choice' ORDER BY town_name ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row{'town_name'} . "</option>";
}
```

This works perfectly for any 'county_name' variable that is 1 word i.e London, Essex. But when they pick 'East Sussex' for example, it returns nothing.

I thought the mysql_real_escape_string was the problem, so I removed that and yet the problem was still occurring.

The javascript to plug the data into the second drop down is as follows:

```
$(function() {              
$("#select_county").change(function() {
$("#select_town").load("include_mx/getter.php?choice=" + $("#select_county").val());
    });     
});
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why the 'spaces' in-between are having no success.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How can I make it more secure? I thought the real_escape_string would suffice?

Comment: You are right, that is what `mysql_real_escape_string` does.  However, we don't know what it does to the space, which is your problem.  Look at it in the debugger.

Comment: It seem's to return the URL -getter.php?choice=West%20Sussex ,would the %20 be the problem?

Comment: Yep, I don't think SQL will match `West Sussex` and `West%20Sussex`.  But that is not mysql_real_escape_string.  The browser is doing it.  Try pasting a url into your browser with a space in it.  The space will change to `+` or `%20`.  This is called URL encode in .net -- I don't know the function in PHP to undo it, but I imagine it exists.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the %20 thats the problem at the moment, i've tried encoding it to be presented with West+Sussex, but I dont want it displaying like that to the user?!

Comment: hmm... I'm not a php guy, but you could try to send it to the user with all spaces replaced by `&npsp;` and then convert `&npsp;` to space before the sql call.

Comment: I am unsure of the quickest most simplest answer, how ever, this works for me:

Any county with a 'space' has been replaced with 'West+Sussex': 

    str_replace(" ","+","$variable");
Because I didn't want to show the '+'s I used this:

    $c=$row['county_name'];
    $county = str_replace("+"," ","$c");
    echo "<option value='$c'>$county</option>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of the quickest most simplest answer, how ever, this works for me:

Any county with a 'space' has been replaced with 'West+Sussex':

```
`str_replace(" ","+","$variable");
```

Because I didn't want to show the '+'s I used this:

```
$c=$row['county_name']; $county = str_replace("+"," ","$c"); echo "<option value='$c'>$county</option>";
```

That seem's to work all the time now and is pretty robust.